# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/customRegisterForm/UploadImageViewSet/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: reactjs, django, web, web-applications, react-fullstack

While Posting the image from react JS using fetch operation getting the error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) and for backend used django

Error in console: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJSYN.png)

Here is React JS code:

UploadImages.js

```
import React from "react"

export default function UploadImages() {

    const [picture, setPicture] = React.useState({})

    function data(event) {
        setPicture((prevPicture) => {
            return {
                ...prevPicture,
                [event.target.name]: [event.target.value]
            }
        })
    }

    console.log(picture)

    function handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/customRegisterForm/UploadImageViewSet/", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                upload_name: picture.upload_name,
                image_upload: picture.image_upload,
            }),
            header: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        });
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="picture.upload_name" onChange={data} placeholder="Name" value={picture.upload_name} /><br />
                <input type="file" name="picture.image_upload" onChange={data} accept="image/jpeg, image/png" value={picture.image_upload} /><br />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )

}
```

Models.py

```
class UploadImage(models.Model):
    upload_name = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to="UserUploadImage/", blank=True, null=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class UploadImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadImage
        fields = ('id', 'upload_name', 'image_upload')
```

Url.py

`router.register("UploadImageViewSet", UploadImageViewSet)`

Views.py

```
class UploadImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UploadImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadImageSerializer
```

I tried all the possibilities but did not get the solution, please help.

Need solution for POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/customRegisterForm/UploadImageViewSet/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)